# Showing a particular subgroup is normal

Tags: group-theory

$G$ is a finite group with identity $e$. $G$ has the property that, for some fixed integer $n > 1$,
$$
(xy)^n = x^ny^n\qquad \text{for all $x,y$ in $G$.}\tag{1}
$$

Let $G_1 = \{g \in G : g^n = e\}$, $G_2 = \{x^n : x \in G\}$. We are asked to show that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are normal subgroups.

I succeeded in showing $G_1$ is normal by showing it is the kernel of the homomorphism that takes $y\in G$ to $y^n$, which is a homomorphism because $G$ satisfies property (1). We also know from this that $G_2$ is isomorphic to $G/G_1$.

I am having trouble showing $G_2$ is normal. I tried showing it was closed under conjugation but didn't manage to. And I couldn't come up with a homomorphism whose kernel is $G_2$.

Comment: All you need is $$yx^ny^{-1} = (yxy^{-1})^n$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the given identity, it's easily verified that $G_2$ is a subgroup of $G$.

To prove it's a normal subgroup, let $x\in G_2$, and let $g\in G$.

Since $x\in G_2$, we have $x=y^n$, for some $y\in G$.

Note that 
\begin{align*}
(gyg^{-1})^2 &= (gyg^{-1})(gyg^{-1})=gy^2g^{-1}\\[4pt]
(gyg^{-1})^3 &= (gyg^{-1})(gyg^{-1})(gyg^{-1})=gy^3g^{-1}\\[4pt]
&\;\;\vdots\\[4pt]
(gyg^{-1})^n &= (gyg^{-1})\cdots(gyg^{-1})=gy^ng^{-1}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence
$$gxg^{-1} = gy^ng^{-1} = (gyg^{-1})\cdots (gyg^{-1})=(gyg^{-1})^n$$
so $gxg^{-1}\in G_2$.

Hence, $G_2$ is normal in $G$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $G_2$ is the image of a homomorphism, it is a subgroup. And much more is true: $G_2$ is a fully invariant subgroup. Indeed, if $\varphi$ is an endomorphism of $G$, then
$$
\varphi(x^n)=(\varphi(x))^n
$$